# Inconsistency in UI: favorite stars are of different colors

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, profile-page, bookmarks, question-lists

When I am looking at the first page https://stackoverflow.com/users/303863/chao-xu?tab=questions&sort=votes I (incorrectly) see all the stars in white. But when I am looking at the second page [Languages that can alter its own syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6809370/languages-that-can-alter-its-own-syntax) I correctly see the star in yellow (because I favored the question).

How to fix: Change display on the first page, that is, to display one of the stars (namely the star that corresponds to my favored question) in yellow.

At the same time, it seems to me that all stars on the first page have to be non-clickable, i.e. current non-clickable behavior is correct.

**UPDATE:** at the same time, all the stars at https://stackoverflow.com/users/303863/chao-xu?tab=favorites are incorrectly yellow, but I favored no one of questions in the list.

// feel free to correct my english

Comment: Ok, so the issue here: If you favorite your own question, it doesn't show as favorited in your questions list on your profile, when viewed by you. *Reproduced.*

Comment: @animuson It seems that I reported something different. I favored question of **another** person, and it doesn't show as favored on first (infrequently visited) page, but do show as favored on second (i.e. traditional) page.

Comment: Ah, I see. So then the issue is probably that the questions list on the profile page does not show favorites properly at all.

Comment: @animuson Yes, it is.

Comment: @animuson I updated this question instead of opening another one; am I correct?

Answer (score 2):

We only use the yellow stars when you have:

- Favorited a question
- Can unfavorite it (ie. the star is clickable)

This means you'll only see the yellow stars on the question itself, and the favorites tab in your profile.  Everywhere else the favorite star only shows the total number of people who have "favorited" a question.

> [At] the same time, all the stars at
>   https://stackoverflow.com/users/303863/chao-xu?tab=favorites are
>   incorrectly yellow, but I favored no one of questions in the list.

Yes you did, you've probably just forgotten.  After all, you favorited some of those posts more than a year ago.